# Intermittent exception in storyboard in UWP/Winrt applcation

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-runtime, win-universal-app

I am receiving the following exception intermittingly when triggering a storyboard on a user control through a View State.

*WinRT information: Cannot resolve TargetProperty (Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color) on specified object*

My storyboard is below -

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup>
                <VisualState x:Name="Connecting">
                    <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Bd1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                            <DiscreteColorKeyFrame Value="#F7F7F7" KeyTime="0:0:0" />
                            <DiscreteColorKeyFrame Value="#6CBF25" KeyTime="0:0:1" />
                            <DiscreteColorKeyFrame Value="#F7F7F7" KeyTime="0:0:5" />
                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Bd1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                            <DiscreteColorKeyFrame Value="#919191" KeyTime="0:0:0" />
                            <DiscreteColorKeyFrame Value="#01851F" KeyTime="0:0:1" />
                            <DiscreteColorKeyFrame Value="#919191" KeyTime="0:0:5" />
                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <Border x:Name="Bd1" Height="5" />
    </StackPanel>
```

And how I trigger it

```
VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Connecting", false);
```

This visual state is generally triggered immediately on UserControl load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its failing because there isn't a `SolidColorBrush` defined on `Bd1`. 
`Background` is of type `Brush` so you could initilaise with a SolidColorBrush like so and your animation should work. I added `BorderBrush` as well as you're animating that and a `Width` so you can see it on the screen

```
<Border x:Name="Bd1" Width="200" Height="5" Background="Red" BorderBrush="Red" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Your border has no default color. Therefore you can´t access it from Storyboard.

This will work:

```
<StackPanel Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="BorderAnimationGroup">
            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0"/>
            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
            <VisualState x:Name="Connecting">
                <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Bd1">
                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FFF7F7F7"/>
                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="#FF6CBF25"/>
                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:5" Value="#FFF7F7F7"/>
                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Bd1">
                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF919191"/>
                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="#FF01851F"/>
                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:5" Value="#FF919191"/>
                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <Border x:Name="Bd1" BorderBrush="#FF919191" BorderThickness="1" Height="5" Background="White">
        <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                <Core:GoToStateAction StateName="Connecting"/>
            </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
        </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </Border>
</StackPanel>
```